# Amazon SES Emails in Bulk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I am trying to setup an email queue via Amazon SES to make sure I can send multiple emails at the sametime (limited to 14 emails per second).

I am constantly getting a sign in error

> The email was not sent. Error message: Error executing "SendEmail" on "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: Sender SignatureDo (truncated...) SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. The Canonical String for this request should have been 'POST / aws-sdk-invocation-id:4d2929e4b7ca73cfe9370d1b848d398d aws-sdk-retry:0/0 host:email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com x-amz-date:20170311T031541Z aws-sdk-invocation-id;aws-sdk-retry;host;x-amz-date 486b4c1288d7c5717c3a0bccdaf10f67eb02ca5da8fbfed75298e98e8f785048' The String-to-Sign should have been 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20170311T031541Z 20170311/us-west-2/email/aws4_request ce02f756d98ab45ab63754fd6ec64a6621c36ed802316ff22c2c877535925735' - Sender SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. The Canonical String for this request should have been 'POST / aws-sdk-invocation-id:4d2929e4b7ca73cfe9370d1b848d398d aws-sdk-retry:0/0 host:email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com x-amz-date:20170311T031541Z aws-sdk-invocation-id;aws-sdk-retry;host;x-amz-date 486b4c1288d7c5717c3a0bccdaf10f67eb02ca5da8fbfed75298e98e8f785048' The String-to-Sign should have been 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20170311T031541Z 20170311/us-west-2/email/aws4_request ce02f756d98ab45ab63754fd6ec64a6621c36ed802316ff22c2c877535925735' 028b5fb9-0609-11e7-9549-6d5ec2e3cc18

and I tried other solutions on stackoverflow without success.

PHP code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// aws.amazon.com/code/
// docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-php.html
// Replace path_to_sdk_inclusion with the path to the SDK as described in 
// docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html
define('REQUIRED_FILE','aws/aws-autoloader.php');

// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address. 
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
define('SENDER', 'no-reply@mydomain.com');

// Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
// is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
define('RECIPIENT', 'admin@mydomain.com');

// Replace us-west-2 with the AWS region you're using for Amazon SES.
define('REGION','us-west-2');

define('SUBJECT','Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for PHP)');
define('BODY','This email was sent with Amazon SES using the AWS SDK for PHP.');


require REQUIRED_FILE;

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'version'=> 'latest',
    'region' => REGION,
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => 'xxxx',
        'secret'  => 'xxxx',
    )
));

$request = array();
$request['Source'] = SENDER;
$request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array(RECIPIENT);
$request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = SUBJECT;
$request['Message']['Body']['Text']['Data'] = BODY;

try {
    $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
    $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
    echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo("The email was not sent. Error message: ");
    echo($e->getMessage()."\n");
}
```

You will make my day if you can help.

Comment: I tried regenerated new keys and I still get the same result.

Comment: Can you tell which SDK version you are using? and Have you hearrd about PHPMailer library.

Comment: I am sharing you my code which will definitely work , I am using that in my website.

Comment: I will investigate your question and I will get back to you but I would pay for a "queue" email solution for Amazon SES via php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AWS SES BULK sending library](https://github.com/Sahil-Gulati/MREmail)

[AWS SDK V3 Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html)

**Installation**

**Step 1.**
`Create Composer.json`

`{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.*"
    }
}`

**Step 2.**
`composer install`

[AWS SDK V2 Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html)

[Installation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html)

This code will work for one-to-one sending using SES AWS SDK version 3. Hope this will work. For sending `multiple emails via AWS SES` Use this library [AWS SES BULK EMAIL SENDING](https://github.com/Sahil-Gulati/MREmail)

```
<?php

$sesClient = Aws\Ses\SesClient::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => $accessKey,
                'secret' => $secretKey,
            ),
            "region" => "us-east-1",
            "version" => "2010-12-01"
        ));

$mail = new PHPMailer_PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->AddAddress($receiverEmail);
$mail->setFrom($senderEmail, $senderName);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->preSend();
$mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
try
{
    $response = $sesClient->sendRawEmail(array("RawMessage" => array("Data" => $mime)));
    $MessageId = $response->get("MessageId");
    $metaData = $response->get("@metadata");
    if (!empty($MessageId))
    {
        $sent[]=$MessageId;
        $sent[]=$metaData["headers"]['x-amzn-requestid'];
    }
} catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo $response = $ex->getMessage();
    $xmlResponse = explode('<Code>', $response);
    $parsedResponse = explode('</Code>', $xmlResponse[2]);
    $failed[]=$parsedResponse[0];
}
```

Comment: The code is significantly different I will need to investigate how to test this code. I will need to check with guy who helped me thus far. Could I hire you for a fix via teamviewer?

Comment: Yes sure. Provide me your teamviewer ID

Comment: are you using ubuntu or other OS?

Comment: @Newby sure..  :)

Comment: Okay coming on skype

Comment: Sahil Gulati can you get on skype please I need some help.

Comment: That bulk sending library looks promising. I will test it out.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama Try it out. If you find any issue I will be there to help you with.